# How to fetch Aggregated result on every 3 hours in a specific date in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I've the following table, And I'm trying to fetch total count of products in every 3 hours and Also I want to display **0** if no products exist under a certain period rather than displaying only existed records.

[image]

I'm closer and able get the records on every hour basis but not in the period of 3 hours. Please find the following queries I've used.

```
CREATE TABLE `integers` (
`i` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`i`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
insert  into `integers`(`i`) values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23);
```

and

```
SELECT hr + INTERVAL 1 HOUR AS `date`, COUNT(products.product_id) AS product_count
FROM (  
   SELECT 
     FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)/3600)*3600+1800) - INTERVAL i HOUR AS hr
   FROM integers 
   WHERE i BETWEEN 0 AND HOUR(NOW())) AS times
LEFT OUTER JOIN product AS products 
ON products.`updated_on` >= hr
   AND products.`updated_on`  < hr + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
   AND products.`updated_on` > DATE(NOW())
GROUP 
BY hr
ORDER 
BY hr
```

With the above queries, I'm able to get the aggregated result for every 1 hour and the output as follows

[image]

But I want to make it to every 3 hour duration. I'm missing something somewhere and I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: Do you want the result only for the current date?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yes. For now, Let's keep it for current date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (using *modulo* operator):

```
SELECT hr.i as hr_from,
       hr.i + 3 as hr_to,
       COUNT(p.product_id) AS product_count
FROM integers hr
LEFT OUTER JOIN product AS p
ON p.updated_on >= DATE(NOW())
   AND HOUR(p.updated_on) BETWEEN hr.i and hr.i + 2
WHERE hr.i MOD 3 = 0
GROUP BY hr.i
ORDER BY hr.i
```

Comment: It's giving a single row result, while I'm expecting same output I've mentioned with but with aggregated result for every 3 hours rather than 1 hour

Comment: @KishoreKumarKorada - I forgot the GROUP BY clause. Now fixed.